# How to parse xml/sbml with R package xml?

Tags: r, xml, sbml

I'm trying to parse information from the sbml/xml file below

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10712588/file.xml

from this code

http://search.bioconductor.jp/codes/11172

It seems that I can import the file normally by

```
doc <- xmlTreeParse(filename,ignoreBlanks = TRUE)
```

but I can't recover node attributes by

```
atrr <- xpathApply(doc, "//species[@id]", xmlGetAttr, "id")
```

or

```
xpathApply(doc, "//species", function(n) xmlValue(n[[2]]))
```

A node of the file follows...

```
<species id="M_10fthf_m" initialConcentration="1" constant="false" hasOnly
SubstanceUnits="false" name="10-formyltetrahydrofolate(2-)" metaid="_metaM_10fth
f_m" boundaryCondition="false" sboTerm="SBO:0000247" compartment="m">
        <notes>
          <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <p>FORMULA: C20H21N7O7</p>
            <p>CHARGE: -2</p>
            <p>INCHI: InChI=1S/C20H23N7O7/c21-20-25-16-15(18(32)26-20)23-11(7-22
-16)8-27(9-28)12-3-1-10(2-4-12)17(31)24-13(19(33)34)5-6-14(29)30/h1-4,9,11,13,23
H,5-8H2,(H,24,31)(H,29,30)(H,33,34)(H4,21,22,25,26,32)/p-2/t11-,13+/m1/s1</p>
            <p>HEPATONET_1.0_ABBREVIATION: HC00212</p>
            <p>EHMN_ABBREVIATION: C00234</p>
          </body>
        </notes>
        <annotation>
...
```

I would like to retrieve all information inside species node, anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it depends on what you mean when you say you want to "retrieve" all the information in the species nodes, because that retrieved data could be coerced to any number of different formats. The following assumes you want it all in a data frame, where each row is an species node from your XML file and the columns represent different pieces of information.

When just trying to extract information, I generally find it easier to work with lists than with XML.

```
doc <- xmlTreeParse(xml_file, ignoreBlanks = TRUE)
doc_list <- xmlToList(doc)
```

Once it's in a list, you can figure out where the species data is stored:

```
sapply(x, function(x)unique(names(x)))
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
[1] "species"

[[5]]
[1] "reaction"

[[6]]
[1] "metaid"

$.attrs
[1] "level"   "version"
```

So you really only want the information in `doc_list[[4]]`. Take a look at just the first component of `doc_list[[4]]`:

```
str(doc_list[[4]][[1]])
List of 9
 $       : chr "FORMULA: C20H21N7O7"
 $       : chr "CHARGE: -2"
 $       : chr "HEPATONET_1.0_ABBREVIATION: HC00212"
 $       : chr "EHMN_ABBREVIATION: C00234"
 $       : chr "http://identifiers.org/obo.chebi/CHEBI:57454"
 $       : chr "http://identifiers.org/pubchem.compound/C00234"
 $       : chr "http://identifiers.org/hmdb/HMDB00972"
 $       : Named chr "#_metaM_10fthf_c"
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "about"
 $ .attrs: Named chr [1:9] "M_10fthf_c" "1" "false" "false" ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:9] "id" "initialConcentration" "constant" "hasOnlySubstanceUnits" ...
```

So you have the information contained in the first eight lists, plus the information contained in the attributes.

Getting the attributes information is easy because it's already named. The following formats the attributes information into a data frame for each node:

```
doc_attrs <- lapply(doc_list[[4]], function(x) {
  x <- unlist(x[names(x) == ".attrs"])
  col_names <- gsub(".attrs.", "", names(x))
  x <- data.frame(matrix(x, nrow = 1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  colnames(x) <- col_names
  x
})
```

Some nodes didn't appear to have attributes information and so returned empty data frames. That caused problems later so I created data frames of NAs in their place:

```
doc_attrs_cols <- unique(unlist(sapply(doc_attrs, colnames)))
doc_attrs[sapply(doc_attrs, length) == 0] <- 
  lapply(doc_attrs[sapply(doc_attrs, length) == 0], function(x) {
    df <- data.frame(matrix(rep(NA, length(doc_attrs_cols)), nrow = 1))
    colnames(df) <- doc_attrs_cols
    df
  })
```

When it came to pulling non-attribute data, the names and values of the variables were generally contained within the same string. I originally tried to come up with a regular expression to extract the names, but they're all formatted so differently that I gave up and just identified all the possibilities in this particular data set:

```
flags <- c("FORMULA:", "CHARGE:", "HEPATONET_1.0_ABBREVIATION:", 
  "EHMN_ABBREVIATION:", "obo.chebi/CHEBI:", "pubchem.compound/", "hmdb/HMDB",  
  "INCHI: ", "kegg.compound/", "kegg.genes/", "uniprot/", "drugbank/")
```

Also, sometimes the non-attribute information was kept as just a list of values, as in the node I showed above, while other times it was contained in "notes" and "annotation" sublists, so I had to include an `if else` statement to make things more consistent.

```
doc_info <- lapply(doc_list[[4]], function(x) {
  if(any(names(x) != ".attrs" & names(x) != "")) {
    names(x)[names(x) != ".attrs"] <- ""
    x <- unlist(do.call("c", as.list(x[names(x) != ".attrs"])))
  } else {
  x <- unlist(x[names(x) != ".attrs"])
  }
  x <- gsub("http://identifiers.org/", "", x)
  need_names <- names(x) == ""
  names(x)[need_names] <- gsub(paste0("(", paste0(flags, collapse = "|"), ").+"), "\\1", x[need_names], perl = TRUE)
  #names(x) <- gsub("\\s+", "", names(x))
  x[need_names] <- gsub(paste0("(", paste0(flags, collapse = "|"), ")(.+)"), "\\2", x[need_names], perl = TRUE)
  col_names <- names(x)
  x <- data.frame(matrix(x, nrow = 1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  colnames(x) <- col_names
  x
})
```

To get everything together into a data frame, I suggest the `plyr` package's `rbind.fill`.

```
require(plyr)

doc_info <- do.call("rbind.fill", doc_info)
doc_attrs <- do.call("rbind.fill", doc_attrs)

doc_all <- cbind(doc_info, doc_attrs)


dim(doc_all)
[1] 3972   22

colnames(doc_all)
 [1] "FORMULA:"                    "CHARGE:"                     "HEPATONET_1.0_ABBREVIATION:" "EHMN_ABBREVIATION:"         
 [5] "obo.chebi/CHEBI:"            "pubchem.compound/"           "hmdb/HMDB"                   "about"                      
 [9] "INCHI: "                     "kegg.compound/"              "kegg.genes/"                 "uniprot/"                   
[13] "drugbank/"                   "id"                          "initialConcentration"        "constant"                   
[17] "hasOnlySubstanceUnits"       "name"                        "metaid"                      "boundaryCondition"          
[21] "sboTerm"                     "compartment"
```

Comment: Thank you very much SchaunW, it exactly what I needed, I really would like to use something with official support, because this formats are constantly changing, but I lost a lot of time with rsmbl package.

Answer (score 4):

There exists an SBML parsing library libSBML (http://sbml.org/Software/libSBML).

This includes a binding to R that would allow access to the SBML objects directly within R using code similar to

```
document  = readSBML(filename);

errors = SBMLErrorLog_getNumFailsWithSeverity(
            SBMLDocument_getErrorLog(document), 
            enumToInteger("LIBSBML_SEV_ERROR", "_XMLErrorSeverity_t")
         );


if (errors > 0) {
  cat("Encountered the following SBML errors:\n");
  SBMLDocument_printErrors(document);
  q(status=1);
}

model = SBMLDocument_getModel(document);

if (is.null(model)) {
  cat("No model present.\n");
  q(status=1);
}

species = Model_getSpecies(model, index_of_species);

id = Species_getId(species);
conc = Species_getInitialConcentration(species)
```

There is a Species_get(NameOfAttribute) function for each possible attribute; together with Species_isSet(NameOfAttribute); Species_set(NameOfAttribute) and Species_unset(NameOfAttribute).

The API is similar for interacting with any SBML element.

The libSBML releases include R installers that are available from

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sbml/files/libsbml/5.8.0/stable

navigating to the R_interface subdirectory for the OS and architecture of your choice.

The source code distribution of libSBML contains an examples/r directory with many examples of using libSBML to interact with SBML in the R environment.

Comment: Hi Sarah, thanks for your answer, I had a problem with the code above species = Model_getSpecies(model, index_of_species);
Error in mapply(class, list(...)) : object 'index_of_species' not found, I was trying xml because rpackage rsmbl only worked for level="1", and I lost all my code, I will have a look at the examples, if you know this erros I will be glad if you answer again.

Comment: @user1265067 Note that the rsbml package is not the same as the libSBML's R interface. (Sorry if you already know that – it wasn't clear from the paragraph above.)

Comment: Hi mhucka, It's true, I was not clear, but I knew, I meant is that I was given up tools dedicated to sbml and trying to treat the file as a xml and retrieve information in more generic way.

Comment: Actually index_of_species is not intended as an object. I used it to mean an integer representing the index of the species in a list that is contained within the model.

Answer (score 1):

As a partial answer, the document uses name spaces, and 'species' is part of the 'id' name space. So

```
> xpathSApply(doc, "//id:species", xmlGetAttr, "id", namespaces="id")
 [1] "M_10fthf_c"   "M_10fthf_m"   "M_13dampp_c"  "M_h2o_c"      "M_o2_c"      
 [6] "M_bamppald_c" "M_h2o2_c"     "M_nh4_c"      "M_h_m"        "M_nadph_m" 
 ...
```

with `id:species` and `namespaces="id"` being different from what you illustrate above.